# How to report success and navigate after form submitted using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, overlay

I realized a overlay form but I am having problem on submit.
I post the link to the form and the jQuery code

Link to the page: http://www.all-forevents.com/test/provaajax.htm

```
$("#entra").click (function(e){


e.preventDefault();
//recupera tutti i valori del form automaticamente
var dati = $("#area-login").serialize();
var msg = "Invio con successo";

//questo alert per capire come vengono passati i dati
//alert(dati);

//invio
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "inviaok.asp",
cache: false,
contentType:false,
processData:false,  
dataType: 'text',
data: dati,
dataType: "html",
success: function(xmlHttp) {
       if (xmlHttp.code != 200) 
{top.location.href = '/default.asp';}

    }

 // error: function()
// {alert("Chiamata fallita, si prega di riprovare...");}

});//ajax

});//bottone click
```

The results that I expect are:

1. I want that the user see the message that It is OK
2. I want a redirect to a specified page